# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

**Can someone tell me the solution to this problem? I am getting error please help Its giving me error like  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object' **

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IProperty } from '../property/IProperty.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HousingService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getAllProperties(): Observable<IProperty[]>{
return this.http.get('data/properties.json').pipe(
  map(data => {
    const propertiesArray: Array<IProperty> = [];
    for (const id in data){
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        propertiesArray.push(data[id]);
      }
    }
    return propertiesArray;
  })
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your code you are basically getting all the values from properties `JSON`. The reason you are getting that error is because the data has as type `{}`, because you do not specify it in the generic `get<T = {}>()` method.

A bit of rewriting would result in this:

```
getAllProperties(): Observable<IProperty[]>{
  return this.http.get<Record<string, IProperty>>('data/properties.json').pipe(
    map(data => Object.values(data));
  };
}
```

And you'll be good to go.